# How to establish a network on a Linux single board computer?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a single board computer (SBC) running Linux (Ubuntu 18) that acts as a web server. When the computer is connected to my home Wi-Fi network I can access the webpage being served through the following address:

```
http://ip_address/my_webpage
```

What I'd like to do is modify my setup so that the SBC establishes its own network and does not rely on there being Wi-Fi setup in whatever environment it is operating in.

How would I go about doing this? Note that I do not need the SBC to be able to access the Internet, I just need to be able to access the web page it serves wirelessly.

The end result I'm imagining is that I'll be able to see my SBCs own network in the list of networks available on my laptop, connect to it and access the webpage. However, it would be even better if I could access the SBCs network without having to disconnect my laptop from its usual Wi-Fi network.

In terms of hardware, is it as easy as just buying a router for the SBC to permanently connect to?

If someone could point me in the right direction this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Does it have an ethernet port?

Comment: 3 ways: 1) use a wifi router, and preferably connect the SBC with wired ethernet or you'll be sending the traffic over wifi twice 2) have the SBC set up an ad-hoc wifi network 3) if it supports it, put the SBC's wifi into access point mode

Comment: Excellent! Yes the SBC does have an ethernet port. So can I just buy any WiFi router plug it in, configure the network and then access my webpage being served form the SBC? I guess I'm looking for the solution that'll be most reliable. What do you mean by an ad-hoc wifi network? Could you recommend any instructions to follow to put the SBC into access point mode? I'm wondering what the simplest and most reliable solution could be.

Comment: @Pyy - We cannot recommend learning material.  If you have a specific question about a specific step, we can help you, but you must perform an adequate amount of research before asking that question.

Comment: if your home wifi appliance have ethernet port too, just by a RJ45 and connect both.